# Background-image не отображается

Tags: css, вёрстка

Структура проекта

[image: Структура проекта]

в jquery.dataTables.css :

```
 table.dataTable thead .sorting {
  background-image: url("../images/sort_asc.png");
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
  background-image: url("../images/sort_asc.png");
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
  background-image: url("../images/sort_desc.png");
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled {
  background-image: url("../images/sort_asc_disabled.png");
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
  background-image: url("../images/sort_desc_disabled.png");
}
```

Структура папки не менялась, скачал и поставил, но картинки не отображаются, уже пробовал различные махинации с путем и папкой images все равно не получается, даже если браузер не пишет об ошибке все равно нет картинки. Что делать?

Comment: откройте хром дебаг, наведите на элемент и посмотрите, есть ли эти стили. откройте background image в табе и посмотрите куда на самом деле за картинкой обращается браузер и что сервер возвращает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так: `background-image: url("./web/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.21/images/название.png");`
Убедитесь, что в папке images есть файл с таким именем.

Если не сработает, напишите, где именно находится html файл, в который вы подключаете этот css

Comment: Он находится в папке web

Comment: тогда `background-image: url("./DataTables/DataTables-1.10.21/images/название.png");`

Comment: все равно не работает, дичь какая-то, в браузере он видит написанный адрес как http://localhost:8080/WebBD/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.21/images/sort_both.png

Answer (score 0):

```css
table.dataTable thead .sorting {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("../images/sort_asc.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Не сработало, эти css применяются для head таблицы где находятся кнопки сортировки, а рядом этот css должен выводить стрелочку, ну типо прямая или обратная сортировка, по вашему примеру поправил css и у меня head таблицы поплыл...

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему: у меня страница была с путем "/" от того http://localhost:8080/WebBD/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.21/images/sort_both.png не читался